# What is the Difference between ASCE and IBC Code?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, building-design

What is the fundamental difference between the ASCE Code and IBC Code and what is the objective of each one?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to ASCE 7 *Minimum Design Loads and Associated Criteria for Buildings and Other Structures*, it's important to note that this document is not a code. It is a standard, published by ASCE. This standard is referenced by the International Building Code, which has legal force when adopted by a jurisdiction.

Comment: Hi CableStay thank you for your reply, so in reality if someone wants to refer to a legal issue if occurred in the structural design he must refer to IBC not the ASCE 7 since it is a code and have the legal force?

Comment: The ASCE 7 is a reference document of the IBC and for legal purposes is considered part of the code document. Just like the AISC or ACI specifications are referenced by IBC. The legal issue arises based on what the prevailing jurisdiction adopts. However if the IBC is adopted in full then it is implied that all of the reference documents are also adopted.

Comment: Just a quick read through chapter 1 of the IBC will answer alot of these questions...

Comment: This code search tool I'm developing could also help you answer other open questions you may have about ACI 318-14, AISC 360-16, ASCE 7-16, IBC 2018, IFC 2015 and, NFPA 101-2015.  Check out the video of how it works: https://constructment.com/